# How to count consecutive value change to zero in column python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

from dataframe want to  check how many times value change to zero in columns.

here is input df

```
pd.DataFrame({'value1':[3,4,7,0,11,20,0,20,15,16],
             'value2':[2,2,0,8,8,2,2,2,5,5],
             'value3':[7,10,20,4008,0,1,4820,1,1,1]})
 value1  value2  value3
0       3       2       7
1       4       2      10
2       7       0      20
3       0       8    4008
4      11       8       0
5      20       2       1
6       0       2    4820
7      20       2       1
8      15       5       1
9      16       5       1
```

desired output:

```
df_out=pd.DataFrame({'value1_count':[2],
             'value2_count':[1],
             'value3_ount':[1]})
 value1_count  value2_count  value3_ount
0             2             1            1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
df.eq(0).astype(int).diff().eq(-1).sum()

Out[77]:
value1    2
value2    1
value3    1
dtype: int64
```

To get exact your output, just add the following

```
df.eq(0).astype(int).diff().eq(-1).sum().to_frame().T.add_suffix('_count')

Out[85]:
   value1_count  value2_count  value3_count
0             2             1             1
```

Comment: you may want to update your answer because given expected output is new data frame with new column names

Comment: @DishinHGoyani: I thought making series to dataframe is  trivial, so I just leave it as series. As you said. I edited to make it as expected output :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's something you can do

```
df_out=pd.DataFrame({'value1_count':[df['value1'].value_counts()[0]],'value2_count':[df['value2'].value_counts()[0]],'value3_count':[df['value3'].value_counts()[0]]})
```

Output

```
    value1_count    value2_count    value3_count
0         2              1               1
```

.value_counts() returns a pandas.Series object with the frequency of all the values, the index being the value. So at index [0] you find the frequency of zeros in the column.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> columns_name = ['value1_count','value2_count','value3_ount']
>>> df_out = pd.DataFrame((df==0).sum().values.reshape(1,-1), columns=columns_name )
>>> df_out
   value1_count  value2_count  value3_ount
0             2             1            1
```